# Fourier method for 1D parabollic PDE - not enough conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have the following problem:

- $ 1.5 \cdot c_x{_x} = c_t $
- $ x \in (0,50)$
- $c(x,0) = 3 e ^{-0.03x}$

and I am supposed to solve this with Fourier method. I did the separation and everything, but I got stuck without boundary (or other) conditions. I was told that there *is* a way to solve this and that *apparently* I did not understand the Fourier method enough... I am really struggling here, could someone help me understand and solve this? Thank you :)

I did the following (in short):

- $1.5 \cdot X(x)'' \cdot T(t) = X(x) \cdot T(t)'$
- $\frac{1.5 \cdot X''}{X} = \frac{T'}{T} = - \lambda$
- $1.5 \cdot X'' + \lambda \cdot X = 0$

$X(x) = k_1 \cdot  \sin(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{\lambda}x) + k_2 \cos(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{\lambda}x)$

- $T' + \lambda \cdot T = 0$

$T(t) = k_3 \cdot  e^{-0.03x}$

- $c(x,t) = X(x) \cdot T(t) = (k_1 \cdot  \sin(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{\lambda}x) + k_2 \cos(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{\lambda}x)) \cdot (k_3 \cdot  e^{-0.03x}) $

I also implemented the initial condition for $c(x,0)$ and got stuck right after that.

Comment: you can use Fourier transformation

Comment: well, you need some kind of boundary condition ...